# tkinter module not found error on Sublime text

Tags: python, linux, tkinter, module, sublimetext

I am following some Python tutorials from FreeCodeCamp and, doing exactly as the instructor does on the tutorial, I get this error when trying to run my script:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/user/Programming/Games.py", line 6, in 
from tkinter import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'

I have downloaded 'tkinter' using the command line on my terminal (I run Pop OS) and my source code editor is Sublime Text, in case this information is relevant.

My question is, how do I get the program to find the module tkinter?

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you run your code from a terminal, does it work there? This question is only relevant to the Sublime Text tag if running it from the terminal works  but from Sublime it doesn't (in which case there are remedies).